# Trying to find a neat way of iteratively generating new variables with column names from a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the number of times certain keywords appear in a vector of (pretty long) strings, and to do this over many different sets of keywords.

This is a mock-up of what I'm working with:

A column with the strings to be analysed,

```
passages <- tribble(~texts,
                    "Mary had a little lamb",
                    "Old MacDonald had a farm",
                    "The big friendly giant")

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  texts                   
  <chr>                   
1 Mary had a little lamb  
2 Old MacDonald had a farm
3 The big friendly giant
```

and a tibble where one column denotes the category the keywords fall under, and another column which contains vectors with all the keywords for that category.

```
wordlists <- tribble(
  ~category, ~keywords,
  "animal", c("lamb", "sheep", "dog"),
  "place", c("farm", "meadow"),
  "adjective", c("little", "big", "friendly", "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  category  keywords 
  <chr>     <list>   
1 animal    <chr [3]>
2 place     <chr [2]>
3 adjective <chr [3]>
```

I also have a short function to count the number of times that keywords from a given list appear in a given passage.

```
keywordCount <- function(string, keywords){
  sum(str_count(string, paste("\\b", keywords, "\\b", sep="")))
}
```

I wanted the end result to be something like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  texts                    animal place adjective
  <chr>                     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Mary had a little lamb        1     0         1
2 Old MacDonald had a farm      0     1         0
3 The big friendly giant        0     0         2
```

which means my code needs to

1. Go to row #1 of the `wordlists` tibble, create a new column with the name given by the `category` column
2. The values in this new column should be equal to `keywordCount(texts, keywords)` where `texts` is a passage and `keywords` is a list of words
3. Repeat for rows #2 and #3 of `wordlists`

I'm having problems getting the outcome I want, and other questions I've looked through that seem similar tend to differ slightly in structure from my problem. The most problematic step is creating the column names based on the `category` column of `wordlists`. Also, I have a feeling I could do all this with a for-loop, but I'm also curious if there's a more efficient way to do all this given that the real passages I'm working with are really long (on average tens of thousands of words).

I know there's not much to go on, but I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Apologies, I changed one example to make the end result more distinct and forgot to change the keywords accordingly. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

For each `texts` value we `keywordCount` `wordlists$keywords`  and get a count. We then convert this to dataframe and assign it name using `setNames`.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(sapply(passages$texts, function(x) 
         mapply(keywordCount, x, wordlists$keywords)))), wordlists$category)

#                         animal place adjective
#Mary had a little lamb        1     0         1
#Old MacDonald had a farm      0     1         0
#The big friendly giant        0     0         2
```

---

Similarly, using `purrr` functions we could do

```
library(purrr)

do.call(rbind.data.frame, map(passages$texts, 
                      ~map2_dbl(.x, wordlists$keywords, keywordCount))) %>%
        set_names(wordlists$category)
```